Who is the highest rated player to play in the World Junior
As the title says who is the highest FIDE rated player to play in the World Juniors in any year (rating at the time of playing the tournament). In 2024 it was 2627 but 2700chess shows more than 10 players with a rating above that. I also haven't noticed any 2700+ player playing World Juniors in recent years but I don't know what it was like in the past.

MVL was rated 2718 when he won in 2009.

@Zacky also he was top seed that year. now need to find if there ever was a player >2718 who played any other year
